# Mapper tasks to work on different set of database columns

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

We have a scenario where we want a single Hadoop job to create/manage multiple mapper tasks where each mapper task will query a subset of columns in a relational database table. We looked into DataDrivenDBInputFormat, but that only seems to facilitate partitioning where each mapper task can query a subset of rows in a relational database table.

Appreciate any suggestions in this regard. Thanks.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: And the mappers work against the same rows, just different columns, right?

Comment: Oracle. Yes, the mappers work against the same rows, just different columns.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write a single mapper that reads the union of the two sets of columns.  You  could perform multiple mapper tasks in the same mapper or just dump the data into a sequential file with multiple subsequent mappers using only what they need from that file.  It depends on how related the two sets of mapper outputs are to one another and how quickly, if ever, they get input into the same hadoop step later in the flow.